# how to improve performance of Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.04, windows, windows-7

My Dell have 3GB RAM. In Windows 7, I can easily get **22-25 mbps copying speed**
but here in **Ubuntu** I am getting only **7-8 mbps**. I even installed zRam.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:shnatsel/zram
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install zramswap-enabler
```

this also did not worked.

Please tell me how can I improve my laptop's performance?

Comment: Copying *from* what *to* what, *over* what? And why would you expect zram to improve anything related to disk throughput?

Comment: copying from external hard disk..via google i got this link
[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://ubuntuportal.com/2012/05/how-to-increase-performance-ubuntu-pclaptop-with-low-ram.html

so i installed zRam

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I don't think zram would help you at all, unless your physical memory usage is being capped (which it likely isn't for file transfers).

It might possibly be related to the driver in-use for the hard drive controller (assuming SATA). May need more information though, like laptop specs, and/or model.

Comment: i have Dell Inspiron 15R(N5010)

Comment: same model [1]: http://www.techradar.com/reviews/pc-mac/laptops-portable-pcs/laptops-and-netbooks/dell-inspiron-15r-697899/specification
with 3 GB RAM